# Easiest way to emulate login for data scraping behind login wall

Tags: python, authentication, finance, scrape

I am trying to scrape data from Yahoo Finance. The data I need is only accessible through the premium subscription which I have purchased. However, whenever I run my scripts to scrape the webpage, it is done outside my login. Thus my script returns -

{"finance":{"result":nullerror:{"code":"unauthorized"description:"User is not logged in"}}}

I would like to emulate my login to Yahoo Finance through python so that I can scrape its premium only data. Any tips?

[This is what the login looks like. It has two steps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrwvK.png)

Comment: Have you looked into [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)? This lets you log in manually then reuse the logged in profile for scripting (the login will normally create a cookie in the profile, so you won't need to keep logging in manually).

Comment: You can also try using browser_cookie3. If you've logged into the site in your browser, then you may be able to use the authorization cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a package called [yahooquery](https://yahooquery.dpguthrie.com/guide/ticker/premium/).  A lot of the premium data is available through that interface. Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.

Also, if you still want to do it yourself, you can look through the [source code](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery/blob/master/yahooquery/login.py) on GitHub to see how I’m logging in with Selenium.